# Conditional aggregation in SQL with multiple conditions for WHEN

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the number of printed pages within certain time horizons (printed today, printed this week, printed this year, printed this month) and have the following SQL query to execute:

```
$select2 = "SELECT 
                IF( station_name =  '',  'Unknown', station_name ) station_name, 
                station_name as db_name,    
                sum(case when year(print_date) = $year then print_pages end) as yearpages, 
                sum(case when (month(print_date) = $month and year(print_date) = $year) then print_pages end) as monthpages, 
                sum(case when (day(print_date) = $day and year(print_date) = $year and month(print_date) = $month) then print_pages end) as daypages, 
                sum(case when (week(print_date) = $week AND year(print_date) = $year AND month(print_date) = $month) then print_pages end) as weekpages
            FROM `file_prints`
            GROUP BY station_name;";
```

However, when I do a var dump on one of the elements in the array outputted as a result of executing the query within Zend PHP framework, I observe that the yearpages and monthpages are well-defined (a value other than NULL is returned) but that both the weekpages and daypages are NULL, as seen below:

```
$rows = $_userTable->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select2);
        var_dump($rows[46]);
        print_r(array_keys($rows[46]));



array(6) { 
    ["station_name"]=> string(15) "uchicagoLIBRARY" 
    ["db_name"]=> string(15) "uchicagoLIBRARY" 
    ["yearpages"]=> string(5) "33391" 
    ["monthpages"]=> string(4) "2498" 
    ["daypages"]=> NULL 
    ["weekpages"]=> NULL } 

Array ( 
    [0] => station_name 
    [1] => db_name 
    [2] => yearpages 
    [3] => monthpages 
    [4] => daypages 
    [5] => weekpages
```

What could be the reason why the daypages and weekpages aren't being processed by the query but monthpages and yearpages are fine?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using case statement you should keep day,week,month,year in order like this for getting days and week.

```
     $select2 = "SELECT IF( station_name =  '',  'Unknown', station_name ) 
                station_name, station_name as db_name, sum(case when 
     (day(print_date) = $day and year(print_date) = $year and  
     month(print_date) = $month) then print_pages end) as daypages, sum(case
     when (week(print_date) = $week AND year(print_date) = $year AND 
     month(print_date) = $month) then print_pages end) as weekpages, 
     sum(case when (month(print_date) = $month and year(print_date) = $year) 
     then print_pages end) as monthpages,sum(case when year(print_date) = 
     $year then print_pages end) as yearpages
                FROM `file_prints`
                GROUP BY station_name;";
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I hope you escaped your variables before you go and execute the query, you might risk sql injection attack with your current implementation.

Those can be null for various reasons:

Could you tell more about the values of your variables? Your `$day` and `$week` variables may not be numeric values. Or your table simply does not have rows with `print_date` values equal to `$day` or `$week`.

Comment: I echoed them out previously and can confirm that both $day and $week are numeric. I also manually checked for the second half of your final paragraph manually in phpmyadmin and that argument does not hold water.

Comment: Sorry, just double checking: Those rows you found that have print_date values equal to `$day`, do the rows also satisfy:
`day(print_date) = $day and year(print_date) = $year and month(print_date) = $month)` ?